# MongoDb nested array query excluding on keyword

Tags: mongodb

Below I have listed three zoos. I'm looking for a mongoDB query that will give me all zoos that have an animal with a `type` other than "dog".  For the below documents, the zoos with number 1 and number 3 should be returned because in the `animal` array there are animals with `type` not equal to `dog`.

```
 {
   "name": "Best zoo ever",
   number: 1,
   "animals": [
     {
       "type": "cat",
       "name": "sylvester"
     },
     {
       "type": "dog",
       "name": "scooby"
     }
   ]
 }

 {
   "name": "nyc zoo",
   number: 2,
   "animals": [
     {
       "type": "dog",
       "name": "scooby"
     }
   ]
 }

 {
   "name": "brooklyn zoo",
   number: 3,
   "animals": [
     {
       "type": "fish",
       "name": "dori"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query with $elemMatch and $ne:

```
 db.zoos.find({ "animals": { $elemMatch: { type: { $ne: "dog" }} }})
```

[$elemMatch docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

[$ne docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)

Comment: Thanks @Joe, however I'm using Meteor and they don't support $elemMatch on the front end queries.

Comment: you know of any other ways to achieve the same query?